# regex to match groups in any order

Tags: java, regex

I am given a command like the following:

```
user login --username <username> --password<password>
```

And the order of regex groups isn't important. Groups which are after --flag can come in any order. I was wondering if there is a more neat way to handle this.

I did it like this:

```
user login (username|password) (\w+) (username | password) (\w+)
```

For example both of the below commands are valid

```
user login username bob password 12345
user login password 12345 username bob
```

I captured both the field and its value. For example in this case, I'm trying to capture username and password. However, if number of groups increases, it will be a bit difficult to handle it using `|` operator.

Comment: I'd suggest you use the appropriate tool : an argument parser https://docs.python.org/fr/3/howto/argparse.html that's the tool used for program that accepts argument and command

Comment: at beginning you set ONE dash before username and password and at the end none, so ? The valid syntax for argument parsing is `-u` (one dash for one letter name) or `--username` 2 dash for word name

Comment: sorry it was a mistake

Comment: Separate extracting options and arguments from checking their values, and better yet: use a proven library instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

Regular Expressions are not the appropriate tool for command line parsing.

Use something like [JCommander](https://jcommander.org) instead.

Comment: Don't want to add a whole other answer but I would personally recommend [picocli](https://picocli.info/) over JCommander any day of the year